# vscodevim - find character - comma remap

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code, vscodevim

I a using `vscodevim` with `VS Code`. I have mapped my `leader` to `comma`:

```
"vim.leader": ",",
```

Now when i do `f<some_character>;`, it works as expected to go the second matched character. But afterwards, the `,` (comma) does not work as it is being used as leader. We can do `F<same_character>` to navigate backward. Is there a way to map backward search (via comma originally) to some other key like `\` (slash).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:noremap` to accomplish what you need. It maps a key non-recursively, which will let you define some other key to have the original behaviour of `,`. With your example:

```
:noremap \ ,
```

Here, `:map` would not work, since `:map \ ,` would make `\` behave like your modified `,` key, so you really need `noremap`.